# Printing only 50 rows per page

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that selects all of the cells that have been edited and prints them.  I have had the print options set to fit to 1 page but when I started to print over 50 rows it was getting to small.  Here is my current Code

```
Dim R As Integer
On Error GoTo 1

R = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("ACM").Range("E1").Font.Color = vbBlack
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(R, 5)).Select

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Selection.Address

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
End With
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

I tried adding 
    ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add.Cell ("A51") 
to make it print only 50 rows per page but this line errors out.

So question: Is there a way to make it so I only print 50 rows one 1 page? A 2nd Question would be can I print the header on the 2nd page?

Comment: what version of Excel are you on?

Comment: I am using Excel 2010

Answer (score 1):

2nd question first: you can repeat headers on future pages by adding this line within your With ActiveSheet.PageSetup block: `.PrintTitleRows = "$3:$3"` (replace the 3's with the start and end row number of your header)

For your first question: check if you still get errors after removing

```
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = 1
```

from your code -- this would eliminate the logical conflict.  Or try adjusting the syntax to `Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = Range("B64")` -- notice the `.Location = Range` instead of `.Add.Cell` (I just recorded a macro).  Finally, check that the page break code is on its own line, not within the `With` block.  Hopefully, one of these 3 suggestions will work.

Comment: Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = Range("A51") gives me an error of Run-Time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: the code sample you posted below has the line ".FitToPagesTall = 0" , I would imagine that would give an error.  Try eliminating both .FitToPages lines.

Comment: actually it doesnt give an error IDK why, The code i posted is what seems to work so far...if I go onto more than 2 pages though the 3rd page only does 49 rows now 50 so i am now trying to resolve that issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You'll need to set the `sht` variable to your sheet name. of just use `ActiveSheet`

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ActiveSheet

'this view needs to be active if you are making changes
'to the page setup which will affect printing.
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview

Dim bottomRow As Long, numberOfPageBreaks As Integer, p As Integer
Dim bottomRange As Range

'or set this manually if you have data with gaps in it
bottomRow = sht.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

'minus 1 for the header row. Adjsut accordingly
numberOfPageBreaks = CInt((bottomRow - 1) / 50)

'print the first row on everypage
sht.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "1:1"

'start with a blank slate
sht.ResetAllPageBreaks

For p = 1 To numberOfPageBreaks
    With sht
        '+1 for the header. + another 1 for 'before'
        Set bottomRange = .Cells((50 * p) + 1 + 1, 1)
        If bottomRange.Row <= bottomRow Then
            Set .HPageBreaks(p).Location = bottomRange 
        End If

    End With
Next p
```

Comment: Still trying to make yours work with my code ill have the results in a few

Answer (score 0):

So I couldnt get Brads suggestion to work but tinkering with ExactaBox I still couldnt get yours to work either.

So after recording macros over and over again I found this solution.

```
R = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("E1").Font.Color = vbBlack
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(R, 5)).Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("A51")
ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = Selection.Address
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ws.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "1:1"
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 0
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

A few things to note is the change of 
    .FitToPagesTall = 0 ' this was a 1 now its a 0

Also 
        .PrintTitleRows = "1:1" ' this does work to print titles thank you ExactaBox

Finally

```
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("A51")
```

This is the line needed to insert a Hpagebreak above Cell 51 allowing only 50 cells on the first page.